# Azure application insights availability from multiple test locations - Are requests fired sequentially or all at one?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, performance-testing, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I have set-up a standard Availability test to my Azure Functions and APIM in Azure, using the standard availability feature in Application Insights. Azure advises to use a minimum of 5 test locations, i.e. the places from where the Azure servers send web requests to my URL:

> Our minimum number of recommended test locations is five to ensure that you can distinguish problems in your website from network issues

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-standard-tests

My questions: Are the tests coming from these 5 locations all fired at once (concurrent processing) or one-by-one (sequentially)? Since the processing of indivual requests by my API could take up to 30 seconds, I want to know how to interpret the average processing times stated in the test results. Concurrent processing can take much longer than sequential processing and taking the average.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am a part of Application Insights team)

Answering the question - neither sequentially nor all at once.

Every location runs tests completely independently from other locations. On top of it, the first test execution is randomized within the first 5 minutes (and after it a test is run every 5 minutes).